# Regex expression to merge elements together

Tags: python

Using lxml it is possible to merge two tags together using regular expression?

```
<t1>test testing </t1>
<t1>testing non. </t1>
```

Notice that one tag has no [.] just wanna merge together with second tag,

```
<t1>test testing testing non.</t>
```

It is possible to solve this problem by using lxml regex?

```
tree.xpath('//t1/[.]')  #trying to figure out the regex to match together
```

Comment: you open to using beautifulsoup?

Comment: prefer lxml instead of beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a little code using lxml etree and XPath, hopefully this is what you needed. What I needed to do though, is to add a "root" to the XML, then I even added a third "t1" tag and the find function is able to find the text within all of the 3 tags contained in the "tests" root.

```
from lxml import etree
        
xml = etree.XML("<tests><t1>test testing </t1><t1>testing non. </t1><t1>this is a random@ test</t1></tests>")
        
find = etree.XPath("//t1")
        
tests = find(xml)
    
tests_text = ''
    
for t in tests:
    tests_text += t.text
    
print(tests_text)
```

I used some references from the lxml documentation, which you can find here https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method.

XPath uses regular expressions by default, and you only need to indicate in the "find" function, which tag you are looking for in your XML, in this case "//t1".